# Another Separable Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks:
Solve the given differential equation by separation of variables.

$x \dfrac{{dy}}{dx}=4y$

Can anyone show me how to do it, please?

Comment: Two comments: please edit your post and please show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally,$$x\frac{dy}{dx}=4y\Longleftrightarrow\frac{dy}{y}=4\frac{dx}{x}.$$
 This is not rigorous : it just tells you what should be the solutions of your differential equation, provided that former algebraic operations are allowed (here I divided by $y$ and $x$, assuming that they were not zero).